# Is there a multi-zone multi-service global dashboard for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, architecture

Is there any easy way to watch the list of all products in AWS for a single account?

I'm currently manually making a "for each geographical zone" "for each service" see it's dashboard, so I can disover I have 4 EC2 instances in Ireland and 2 MySQL databases in Frankfurt for example.

Is it a simple way to see "all the things that are running" (without having to code a script against the API of course, I already know that could be a solution)

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of all resources you've created globally in your account?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I'm not needing to "interact with them" but just "list" all the things spinning here or there. Similarly to when you enter an EC2 dasboard that says "3 security groups, 5 instances, 2 elastic IPs, 4 VPNs"... but including filesystem, s3 buckets, databases and also no only in the current region but for all regions, watching it in a glance.

Comment: CloudHealth, which is a third party product, can probably do it. So can others. I also have some kind of a free plan with https://www.site24x7.com but I can't see on their website what free does compared with paid, and it's more about costs than resources.